# getting jquery datatables + jeditable + makeEditable + autogrow (or elasic) plugins playing nicely together?

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable, autogrow

I'm having some trouble getting all these jquery plugins to play together nicely. Specifically, neither the autogrow nor the elastic plugins seem to work with the datatables and markEditable plugins. Here's a code snippet:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"><\/script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var oTable = $( '#beta' ).dataTable( {
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 7 ] } ],
         "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
         "sDom": 'lfr<"giveHeight"t>ip'
       }).makeEditable( {
            sUpdateURL: "/testdb/cgi-bin/betaTags.cgi",
            "aoColumns": [ null,
                          {
                            indicator: 'Saving Status...',
                            tooltip: 'Click to select tag status',
                            loadtext: 'loading...',
                            type: 'select',
                            submit: 'Ok',
                            data: "{'':'Please select...', '1':'Open','2':'Done','3':'In test'}",
                            sUpdateURL: function(value, settings) {
                               ... some code to handle the select menu
                            }
                          },
                          null,
                          null,
                          {
                            indicator: 'Saving Post Create Problems Note...',
                            tooltip: 'Click to edit Post Create Problems Note',
                            type: 'textarea',
                            submit:'OK',
                            cancel : 'Cancel',
                            sUpdateURL: function(value, settings) {
                               ... some code to handle the textarea cell
                            }
                          },
                          null,
                          {
                            indicator: 'Saving Answer Changes Note...',
                            tooltip: 'Click to update Answer Changes Note',
                            type: 'textarea',
                            submit:'OK',
                            cancel : 'Cancel',
                            sUpdateURL: function(value, settings) {
                               ... some code to handle another textarea cell
                            }
                          }
                      ]
            } );
      } );
    </script>
```

This works fine but when I try to add an autogrow or elastic method to the textarea cells in my dataTable, it doesn't do anything. I've not been able to find many examples that show different jquery plugins working in concert with one another but if someone can point me to some article or resources, it would be much appreciated!